# How to make modal appear onClick change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, jsx, react-bootstrap

I am stuck on getting my Modal to appear when the `Edit` button is clicked. I can see that the `modalShow` is being set to true when I click the button since I console.log the value. Any idea on how to get modal to appear when user clicks the edit button?

`product-screen.jsx`

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Card, Form, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'reactjs-popup/dist/index.css';
import ModalScreen from './modal-screen';

const ProductCardScreen = ({ product }) => {
  const { productName, productPrice, productInStock, productDescription } =
    product;
  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);

  const [updateProduct, setProductUpdate] = useState({
    productDescription,
    productInStock,
    productName,
    productPrice,
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log('event', event.target.value);
    setProductUpdate({
      ...updateProduct,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  // todo
  const saveUpdatedProduct = (product) => {
    // save logic here to db
  };

  const handleDelete = () => {
    alert('Are you sure you want to delete?');
  };

  const handleModalChange = () => {
    console.log('called');
    setModalShow(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Card>
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>Product Name: {product.productName}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>
            Product Description: {product.productDescription}
          </Card.Text>
          <Card.Text>Product Quantity: {product.productInStock}</Card.Text>

          <Card.Text>Price: ${product.productPrice}</Card.Text>
          <div
            style={{
              float: 'right',
            }}
          >
            <Button
              style={{ margin: '10px' }}
              onClick={() => handleModalChange()}
              className='btn btn-primary'
              variant='primary'
            >
              Edit
            </Button>

            <Button
              onClick={() => handleDelete()}
              className='btn btn-danger'
              variant='primary'
            >
              Delete
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>

      <ModalScreen product={product} handleChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductCardScreen;
```

`modal-screen.jsx`

```
import { Button, Form, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';

const ModalScreen = ({ product, handleChange }) => {
  const { productName, productPrice, productInStock, productDescription } =
    product;

  return (
    <Modal
      animation={false}
      size='lg'
      aria-labelledby='contained-modal-title-vcenter'
      centered
    >
      <Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Title id='contained-modal-title-vcenter'>
          Product Information
        </Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <Form>
          <Form.Group className='mb-3'>
            <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={productName}
              type='text'
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group className='mb-3'>
            <Form.Label>Description</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={productDescription}
              type='text'
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group className='mb-3'>
            <Form.Label>Amount In Stock</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={productInStock}
              type='text'
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group className='mb-3'>
            <Form.Label>Price</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={`$${productPrice}`}
              type='text'
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <Button variant='primary' type='button'>
            Save
          </Button>
          <Button variant='danger' type='button'>
            Cancel
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer></Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default ModalScreen;
```

Comment: I think you forgot to pass `modalShow` state to your `ModalScreen` component, so in your  Modal component you can set `visible={modalShow}`

Comment: You are correct @Getsumi3 that was the reason why it was not working. Thanks for your help.